# Need help writing Pig Latin translation code in python

Tags: python

I have a task in which I have to translate english words into pig latin, this means if a word begins with a vowel the word has "ay" added onto the end ("apple" would become "appleay") this wasn't a problem as the code was relatively easy to write.
However, the second part is that if the word begins with a consonant, *all consonants before the first vowel* are removed and added onto the end of the word, with the string "ay" again also being added onto the end after that ("cheese" would become "eesechay").

It's a fairly simple concept but I'm struggling to find a way to translate the word if the word begins with a consonant, here is my code so far:

```
def pigLatin(word):
    for l in vowels:
        if word[0] == l:
            word = word + "ay"
    for L in consonants:
        if word[0] == L:
            for i in vowels:
                for s in word:
                    if s == i:
                        #this is where im completely lost
```

FYI, vowels and consonants are arrays just containing the vowels and consonants, word is inputted by the user.

edit:

thank you for the help, I've managed to re do the code with and get something that works:

```
def pigLatin(word):
    if word[0]in vowels:
        word = word + "ay"
    elif word[0] in consonants:
        c = ""
        for l in word:
            if l in vowels:
                break
            elif l in consonants:
                c = c + l
        word = word[len(c)-len(word):len(word)]
        word = word + c + "ay"
```

again, thank you for the help :)

Comment: Instead of looping over the word yourself, consider letting Python do the work for you. For example, the regex `^([^aeiou]*)([aeiou].*)` will split off the content before the first vowel into a separate matching group from everything after it.

Comment: Per Charles Duffy's comment, regular expressions would certainly do the job.  On the other hand, instead of looping through every vowel/consonant, loop through every letter in your word.  Start by checking whether word[0] is a vowel (e.g. if word[0] in vowels), if it is then you know what to do.  If not, iterate through the letters in word until you find a vowel, move everything before that to the end of the word and add the "ay"

Comment: @CharlesDuffy where in the code would that go? im still confused

Comment: Bluntly -- designing your program for you is outside the scope of what we generally do here; Stack Overflow is focused on being a collection of answers to specific, narrow problems encountered while writing code. "How can I better design a program/algorithm to do X?" has an unlimited set of answers; it's outside that "narrow and specific" specification.

Comment: @tnknepp the problem i have isnt with finding the vowel or consonant its that im not sure where to proceed afterwards   if s == i:    identifies the vowel after ive got the consonant at the beginning of the word, i just dont know what code i need to write to then get all consonants after that vowel and then concatenate that onto the end

Comment: @CharlesDuffy oh ok im sorry its just ive never used a regex before and im not familiar with the code to use one

Comment: @haz This is where looping through the letters in word will help.  As written, you are adding unnecessary complexity (hence confusion).  If you want to stick with your code, then try using enumerate (e.g. for counter, s in enumerate(word):).

Comment: @tnknepp i see what you meant now, i can simplify the code down with what you suggested im still stuck on how to get all the consonants before the vowel and then add them onto the end, ive tried using break to stop the for loop once the first vowel has been found but even that ran into problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Charles Duffy's comment that we don't design programs for you.  However, you're going down the wrong rabbit hole and I think you need a little guidance.  Here is an example of what I was talking about.  There are many ways of doing this, this is a simple solution (one of many).

```
def pigLatin(word):
    vowels = list("aeiou")
    consonants = list("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz")

    if word[0] in vowels:
        word = word + "ay"
    else:
        for counter, letter in enumerate(list(word)):
            if letter in vowels:
                word = word[counter:] + word[:counter] + "ay"
                break

    return word


print(pigLatin("art"))
print(pigLatin("donkey"))
```

What if the word passed into pigLatin contains upper case characters?  You could modify the function by converting everything to lowercase (or upper, your preference).

```
def pigLatin(word):
    vowels = list("aeiou")
    consonants = list("bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz")

    if word[0].lower() in vowels:
        word = word + "ay"
    else:
        for counter, letter in enumerate(list(word)):
            if letter.lower() in vowels:
                word = word[counter:] + word[:counter] + "ay"
                break

    return word
```

Do you get an idea of how much simpler and flexible this code is?

Comment: thank you for this but as you were writing that i took your idea of simplifying down the code to identify the vowel and it really helped me, this is what i got:

Comment: ok it wont let me show the code in that format in the comments for some reason but i do have some code that works now and i diddnt have to copy what you wrote

Comment: @haz You should put this code in your original question as an edit.  Or, if this works, you can post an answer to your own question.

Comment: i edited it into the question @tknepp thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few things that may help:

`ascii_lowercase` in the `string` module is a predefined string containing all lowercase alpha characters:

```
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase
>>> ascii_lowercase
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>>
```

We can generate the set of all consonants, by creating a set of vowels, and taking the difference between the vowels and all characters:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet

vowels = set("aeiou")
consonants = set(alphabet) ^ vowels

print(consonants)
```

Output:

```
{'c', 's', 'q', 'm', 'g', 'd', 'y', 'l', 'b', 'k', 't', 'j', 'r', 'p', 'h', 'v', 'n', 'w', 'z', 'f', 'x'}
>>>
```

Since this is a set, there is no intrinsic order, but that doesn't matter. If we want to know if a given character is a consonant or vowel, we simply check for membership with the corresponding set (you can do the same with lists, but a set would be the preferred data-structure).

Regardless of whether or not you're using lists or sets for your `vowels` and `consonants`, you can simplify your code by simply checking for membership (checking to see if a character is within a collection):

```
if word[0] in vowels:
    # The first letter is a vowel
elif word[0] in consonants:
    # The first letter is a consonant
```

If you know in advance that `word` will only contain lowercase alpha characters (no special symbols, digits, uppercase letters, etc.), then you could simplify it further:

```
if word[0] in vowels:
    # The first letter is a vowel
else:
    # If it's not a vowel, it must be a consonant
```

However, if you think about it, you don't really need to check if the first letter is a vowel, at all. You already know that you'll be adding `"ay"` at the end of the final string, regardless of whether or not the first letter is a vowel or consonant - so, you really just need to check if the first letter is a consonant.

Using everything so far, I would arrive at the following pseudo-code:

```
def to_pig_latin(word):

    from string import ascii_lowercase as alphabet

    vowels = set("aeiou")
    consonants = set(alphabet) ^ vowels

    if word[0] in consonants:
        # Do something

    return ... + "ay"
```

I've renamed the function `to_pig_latin`, since snake-case is preferred, and prefixing the function name with `to` indicates that you are translating/transforming something. I've also moved the creation of `vowels` and `consonants` into the function, just because there's no reason to have it outside of the function, and it's cuter this way.

Comment: thank you for this, you answered when i had got the solution already but it was still informative, ive edited my solution into my initial question so you can take a look at that if you want.